# Ajax no response (multiple upvote buttons on single page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

I need an upvote system that would have the upvote buttons multiple on one page, in a post listing. I took someone elses code that was written with click bind on ids and as the first step I am trying to rewrite it with classes and $(this). It still doesn't work in listing (I need to add $(this) somewhere into the ajax I think) but in single post neither - that is the current problem. The php code returns success but the like count is not updated until I reload - the response is empty

jQuery

```
// ajax get the upvote click
jQuery( '.first' ).bind( 'click', function(){
    jQuery(this).find( '.vmp_message' ).empty();

    //    error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message' + err); }

    jQuery.ajax( {
        url:ajax_object.ajax_url,
        method:'get',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            action:'count_vote_090813',
            post_id:ajax_object.post_id,
            type:'upvote'
        },
        success:function( response ){
            if ( 'error' == response.type ){
                console.log( response );
                //jQuery( '#vmp_message' ).html( response.html );
            }else if( 'success' == response.type ){
                jQuery(this).find( '.vmp_message' ).html( "Success." );
            }else{
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

PHP

```
    $response_type = 'success';

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_2 . "` WHERE `post_id` = " . $post_id;
                    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );

                    if ( 'upvote' == $voting_type ){
                        $html = $result[ 0 ][ 'upvote_count' ];
```

Could someone please explain me
1/ how to debugg this? How do I see in console what's hapenning?
2/ how to bind ajax to $this (if that's the error)

EDIT:

I have found the ajax problem. The problem was the post id information, it has to be done in another way than `post_id:ajax_object.post_id,` if there are multiple posts on a single page. What I did:

In template

```
<div class="bloodylike">
       <a href='javascript:void(0)'  data-postid='<?php echo $my_postid; ?>' class='up_count' title='Click to like this post'>
                    LIKE
             </a>
      </div>
```

In jQuery

```
    var postid = jQuery(this).find( 'a' ).data( "postid" );
    ...
    ...
        data:{
            action:'count_vote_090813',
            post_id:postid,
            type:'upvote'
```

For the response I just added a line to reload it for now, see if I come up with something less lame later.

Comment: Did you try with $.post (...). Because $.get might be caching the resultset.

Comment: I've just tried it, no difference.

Comment: Do this var $this = jQuery(this); and use $this everywhere you used jQuery(this);   the point is that "**this**" inside success function is not the same as "**this**" in jQuery(**this**).find( '.vmp_message' ).empty();